# How to start a django cms project

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I decided to take a look to django-cms. After looking at the docs I cloned the repository using

```
git clone https://github.com/divio/django-cms.git
```

Then I installed it using

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

I already have django 1.2.3 installed. I moved to the `example` directory an ran `syncdb` which created the following tables:

```
Creating table auth_permission
Creating table auth_group_permissions
Creating table auth_group
Creating table auth_user_user_permissions
Creating table auth_user_groups
Creating table auth_user
Creating table auth_message
Creating table django_content_type
Creating table django_session
Creating table django_admin_log
Creating table django_site
Creating table sampleapp_category
Creating table sampleapp_picture
Creating table south_migrationhistory



You just installed Django's auth system, which means you don't have any superusers defined.
Would you like to create one now? (yes/no): yes...
```

We can clearly see that the cms tables are not created. I'm obviously facing that problem when running the server and browsing `http://localhost:8000/`

```
DatabaseError: no such table: cms_page
```

I've looked at the docs and seen that I meet the requirements regarding the versions but clearly, I'm doing something wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the app enabled in the settings file of your project? I think that can very well be the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

django-cms uses [South](http://south.aeracode.org/) for database migrations. Models handled by South are not synced to the database using `syncdb`. You have to use [`manage.py migrate`](http://south.aeracode.org/docs/commands.html#migrate).

Since you don't have any tables and data from django-cms to migrate, a faster solution would be this process:

- comment out `'south'` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`
- run `manage.py syncdb` (this will create all the tables from django-cms)
- re-enable south in your `INSTALLED_APPS`
- run `manage.py migrate --fake`

The next time you update django-cms, you can then run `manage.py migrate` to update your database tables.

Comment: Yes, I followed that as I already used south for other projects. I think the problem is with faking the migrations and not using `migrate --all` afterwards

Answer (score 1):

Did you put `'cms'` in `INSTALLED_APPS` in `settings.py`? Django-CMS furthermore requires also `menus`, `publisher` and `mptt` installed as well as some middleware. [This is some nice to read documentation](http://readthedocs.org/projects/ojii/django-cms/docs/tutorial.html#installation) on it!

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I've been through that tutorial also. I didn't touch to settings.py from the example and it contains cms, menus, publisher and mptt, which i can all import in a python shell.

Answer (score 0):

In general, if tables are not created there can be some errors in the application itself:
try running Django shell and import a model from the application:

```
python manage.py shell

>>> from csm import models
```

and check if you get a traceback.

Hope this can help.